# Add @Html.CheckBoxFor to email asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have checkboxes in my feedback form, it looks like
[image]
I add checkboxes in my model

```
  namespace CorePartners_Site2.Models
 {
public class CareerForm
{
    //...
    public List<CheckBoxes> EmploymentType { get; set; }                                       
 }

public class CheckBoxes
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
 }
```

add to my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CareerForm()
    {
        CareerForm model = new CareerForm();

        model.EmploymentType = new List<CheckBoxes>
        {
            new CheckBoxes { Text = "Fulltime" },
            new CheckBoxes { Text = "Partly" },
            new CheckBoxes { Text = "Contract" }
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

but then I need to add selected checkboxes to email, but I dont know how to do it.
I tried

```
 public ActionResult CareerForm(CareerForm Model, HttpPostedFileBase Resume)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string message = //...
                         "Type: " + Model.EmploymentType;
        msg.Body = message;

    //....
    }
```

but I get in my email just text *Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CheckBoxes]*
How to make it work right?

Comment: Your selected checkboxes in a list, so you should get them in a loop...

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like following

```
string message = "Type: ";

foreach(var item in Model.EmploymentType)
{
    if (item.Checked)
        message += item.Text;
}
```

Comment: I dont try yet, but it looks like I will get all my checkboxes, not only selected.

Comment: @Heidel perhaps you can do something with `if (item.Checked)`... But unchecked checkboxes aren't posted, don't know how the binder will pick that up for your class. Just don't _"think it won't work"_  without trying.

Comment: No, I tried, I actually get all checkboxes, not only selected.

Comment: it doesnt work, because it looks like every my checkbox is selected, because my html-code looks like `<label>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Требуется поле Checked." id="employmentType_1" name="EmploymentType[0].Checked" type="checkbox" value="true">
 <input name="EmploymentType[0].Checked" type="hidden" value="false">
    <input id="EmploymentType_0__Text" name="EmploymentType[0].Text" type="hidden" value="Fulltime">
                                    Fulltime
</label>` and nothing changes in this code when I select any checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model.EmploymentType`  is a  `List<CheckBoxes>`

```
model.EmploymentType = new List<CheckBoxes>
```

You will have to access it's value with index. You are converting to string
a `System.Collection.Generic.`

Comment: I dont understand how to add selected checkboxes to email.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a the text values from each checked checkbox in your list.

This is a list:

```
model.EmploymentType = new List<CheckBoxes>...
```

You want the checked ones:

```
var checked = model.EmploymentType.Where(x => x.Checked);
```

Then you want the `Text` property from those boxes:

```
string message = "Type: " + checked.Text;
```

Put this together inside your controller action and I'd expect it to look like this:

```
public ActionResult CareerForm(CareerForm Model, HttpPostedFileBase Resume)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string message = "Type: ";
    foreach(var box in Model.EmploymentType.Where(x => x.Checked)) {
        message += box.Text + " ";
    }
    msg.Body = message;
}
```

Comment: No, not only one checkbox can be selected, it may be one, two or three.

Comment: Then it will depend how you want the string formatted, but as others have suggested you will need to loop over the collection, pulling out the text properties where the checkbox is checked, editing to that effect.